# external internal validation and chi square

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, independence, goodness-of-fit, bonferroni

The internal test set, created from 20 percent of the train data set, consists of 'a' and 'b' labels. I take the 'a' labels from the internal test and combine them with the 'c' group of another population. This group name is an external validation set. The purpose of asking the following questions is to understand that there is no difference between the test sets created and the train set in terms of age, gender and some other characteristics.
Note: c has the same traits with 'b'. However c come from different location compared to 'b'

1-Can a chi-square test be performed to understand that these test sets do not differ in terms of age(category), education level and gender vb. traits. The purpose is to see they have similar distributions.

2- If I compare the internal and external validation sets with the remaining 80 percent train data set, would it be enough to understand that they have similar characteristics (there is no difference in age and gender)?

3- Each test set is compared to test whether there is any differentiation within the 'a' and 'b' groups. In this case, should Bonferroni be used starting from the first comparison or should Bonferroni be used after the first one?